# Custom Taxonomy link out the loop

Tags: taxonomy

how can i get Custom taxonomy URL by taxonomy ID outside the loop like 
get_category_link();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you're looking for is:

get_term_link();

Here is the Codex entry on it:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link